# How do you clear variables used in order to perform the next correct calculation?

Tags: javascript

I made a calculator for the Odin Project OS Boot Camp I am in. The first calculation is no problem, but after I begin calculating using the result there is an error. I've checked through my code for various days and I have not reached a solid conclusion. My first assumption was that the calculator was running the correct arithmetic functions twice instead of once. My second thought was that I had a typo somewhere, but I could not find anything. This is my first post in any forum, so please go easy on me. If you have any tips on how I can improve my questions or if you need further information please do tell me.

**Here is the full code on codePen that I wrote,**
[calculator(codePen)](https://codepen.io/Alejandroh9800/pen/OJZgJqx)

Here is a snippet of the code:

```js
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
let input = document.querySelector(".calculator_input");
let DEL = document.getElementById("DEL");
let operations = document.querySelectorAll(".enabled");

let enter = document.querySelector(".enter");

function add(a, b) {
  input.textContent = a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  input.textContent = a - b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  input.textContent = a * b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
  if (b !== "0") {
    input.textContent = (a / b).toFixed(2);
  } else {
    input.textContent = "Just Why...";
  }
}

// Delete input from last key pressed.
function back() {
  input.textContent = input.textContent.slice(0, -1);
}

// Clear All from the calculator input.
function erase() {
  input.textContent = "";
  location.reload(); // temporary fix
}
// Gather numbers and operation used in calculation, direct to proper function.
function operate(a, o, b) {
  switch (o) {
    case "+":
      add(a, b);
      break;
    case "-":
      subtract(a, b);
      break;
    case "/":
      divide(a, b);
      break;
    case "*":
      multiply(a, b);
      break;
  }
}

function op() {
  let symbol; //(+, -, *, /)

  // For all operation symbols (+, -, *, /)
  operations.forEach((operation) =>
    // listen for operation click (+, -, /, *)
    operation.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (input.textContent !== "") {
        symbol = operation.dataset.opera; // Save the operation clicked in the variable, Symbol
        let a = parseInt(input.textContent); // Set the first number to be used in the calculation equal to (a)
        input.textContent = ""; // Clear calculator input
        // Listen for enter click
        enter.addEventListener("click", () => {
          let b = parseInt(input.textContent); // Save the next number used in the calculation with (b)
          operate(a, symbol, b); // Begin calculation
          //console.log(`a: ${a}` + ` symbol: ${symbol}` + ` b: ${b}`);
        });
      }
    })
  );
  return symbol; // return operation(+, -, *, /) used for operate()
}

op(); // Start Calculation

// Select all numbers
numbers.forEach((number) =>
  // Check for click, allows for double digit numbers or more to be added to calculation.
  number.addEventListener("click", () => (input.textContent += number.id))
);

// Delete input from last key pressed.
DEL.addEventListener("click", () => back());
// Clear All from the calculator input.
AC.addEventListener("click", () => erase());
```

```css
html{
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.calculator_container{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 60vw; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem; 
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.calculator_input{
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    width: 37vw;
    height: 10vw; 
    color: lime;
    font-size: 3vw;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 2vw;
}

.calculator_name{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.calculator_center{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.calculator_buttons{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1vw;
}

.calculator_buttons > div{
    flex: 1 0 8%;               
    background-color: honeydew;
    padding: 3vw;
    width: max-content;
}

.calculator_buttons > div:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.special{
    background-color: lightcoral !important;
}

.operation{
    background-color: lightyellow !important;
}

.enter{
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

    .calculator_container{
        width: 60vh;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 3rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .calculator_input{
        width: 40vh;
        height: 10vh;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .calculator_name{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

}
```

```html
    <div class="calculator_center">
    <div class="calculator_container">
        <div class="calculator_name">CALC-U-LATER</div>
        <div class="calculator_input"></div>
        <div class="calculator_buttons">
            <div class="special">+/-</div>
            <div class="special" id="AC">AC</div>
            <div class="special" id="DEL">DEL</div>
            <div class="operation enabled" data-opera="+">+</div>
            <div class="operation enabled" data-opera="-">-</div>
            <div class="operation enabled" data-opera="/">/</div>
            <div class="operation enabled" data-opera="*">*</div>
            <div id="9" class="number">9</div>
            <div id="8" class="number">8</div>
            <div id="7" class="number">7</div>
            <div id="6" class="number">6</div>
            <div id="5" class="number">5</div>
            <div id="4" class="number">4</div>
            <div id="3" class="number">3</div>
            <div id="2" class="number">2</div>
            <div id="1" class="number">1</div>
            <div id="0" class="number">0</div>
            <div class="enter">ENTER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are attaching a new click handler on the enter button on every operator button click as long as the input is not empty.

Comment: Adding a new event listener doesn't remove the old one, so you were kind of right in that parts of your code are happening twice (or more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `enter` click handler outside the `operations.forEach` block. You'll also have to instantiate `a` at the top of the `op()` function block. And don't declare variable `a` (`let a`) in the operation click handler block.

```
function op() {

// 1) ---> INSTANTIATE variable a

  let a, symbol; //(+, -, *, /)

  // For all operation symbols (+, -, *, /)
  operations.forEach((operation) =>
    // listen for operation click (+, -, /, *)
    operation.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (input.textContent !== "") {
        symbol = operation.dataset.opera; // Save the operation clicked in the variable, Symbol

// 2) ---> CHANGE "let a = ..." to "a = ..."

        a = parseInt(input.textContent); // Set the first number to be used in the calculation equal to (a)

        input.textContent = ""; // Clear calculator input

// 3) ---> REMOVE event click handler from HERE...

      }
    })
  );

// 4) ---> ...to HERE

  // Listen for enter click
  enter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let b = parseInt(input.textContent); // Save the next number used in the calculation with (b)
    operate(a, symbol, b); // Begin calculation
    //console.log(`a: ${a}` + ` symbol: ${symbol}` + ` b: ${b}`);
  });

  return symbol; // return operation(+, -, *, /) used for operate()
}
```

Handers need only assigned once for each element. Typically they are not assigned more than once. If the handler doesn't change somehow then put put it where it will only be added once.

By putting within, not only the `operations.forEach` iteration, but also with in the `operation` click handler, you're causing the `enter` handler to be added every time an operation button is clicked. This does not overwrite the last `enter` click event hander, it adds ANOTHER `enter` click event handler, with a new, but different instantiation of `a`. And each handler fires for every single "ENTER" button click.

Let's say `enter` has one click event handler, you'll get the correct answer: first number (1) plus second number (2) = 3. But you added a second click hander so now the `enter` button has 2 click handlers.

So the next operation, let's say you click 3 + 4. When you click the "ENTER" button, the first handler will fire but `a` is assigned the first click handler's `a` value: 1, and `b` is assigned your second number: 4, then assign the value 5 to `input.textContent`. But there's now a second click handler to fire. In it `a` gets assigned the second `a` value: 3, and `b` gets the answer to the first handler: 5. 3 + 5 = 8, 8 is now assigned to `input.textContent`. (Whew. :S)

With each click of an operation button yet another `enter` click handler is added, compounding the error and work load.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was bashing my head against the wall for the longest time. Awesome explanation, thanks again!